# Angular route rules

Tags: angularjs, url, routes

I have an AngularJS application. I have two main different kind of routes:

www.mysite.com/{ user1 | user2 | user3 ...}
(those are the users personal pages)

and

www.mysite.com/{ home | profile | settings..}
(those are generic pages for the website)

The problem is that when I go to, for example: www.mysite.com/home, "home" is recognized as a name of the user, and I get the error unexistent user. Right now this route is implemented like that:

```
      $routeProvider.when('/:personalLink/:invoiceUrl', {
          templateUrl: 'pay/pay.html',
          data: {
              needAuth: false
          }
      });
```

How can I add a rule like: follow this route only if :personalLink is not equal to "home", "settings", etc... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use `$routeProvider` then it is better to explicitly  specify the routes one by one. The rule will be matched from top to bottom, so please put the more explicit one on the top, url `:personalLink` works like "wild-chunk-match" but not exactly wild-match :

```
$routeProvider
.when('/home', {
      templateUrl: 'path/to/home_page'
})
.when('/settings', {
      templateUrl: 'path/to/setting_page'
})
.when('/profile', {
      templateUrl: 'path/to/profile_page'
})
.when('/:personalLink/:invoiceUrl', {
      templateUrl: 'pay/pay.html',
      data: {
          needAuth: false
      }
});
```

If you want to use regex pattern in the url path it is better to use [ur-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) :

```
$stateProvider.state("artists-index", {
    url: "/{page:[home|profile|setting]}",
    templateUrl: "/path/to/generic/home_page",
    controller: "*home_page_controller*"
});

$stateProvider.state("artists-index", {
    url: "/{page: user-[0-9a-zA-Z]+}",// it will match 'user-191' for an example
    templateUrl: "/path/to/generic/user_page",
    controller: "*user_page_controller*"
});
```

The regex pattern might to be changed based on your requirement, the one in the code just for demo.

Hope this can help you :)

Comment: Thanks! This actually solved my problem! I had the :personalLink route above the others!